# How to Update Basemap Of ArcGIS API for JS Using jQuery

Tags: jquery, dojo, arcgis-js-api

Can some one please let me know if it is possible to update ArcGIS API Basemap by using jQuery

Here is what I have tried

HTML

```
<select id="base-map-options">
   <option value="0">Imagery</option>
   <option value="1">Topographic With Lable</option>
</select>

   var map;
   var basemap = ['topo','streets','imagarey']
        require([
        "esri/map",
        "esri/layers/ArcGISDynamicMapServiceLayer",
        "dojo/domReady!"
        ], function(Map) {
                            map = new Map("mapDiv", {
                            center: [-126.687482, 54.793577],
                            zoom: 5,
                            basemap: basemap[0]
      });

   $("#base-map-options").on("change", function () {
       basemap[$('option:selected').val()];
    });
});
```

as you can see I am trying to update selected index in `basemap[]` through

```
   $("#base-map-options").on("change", function () {
       basemap[$('option:selected').val()];
    });
```

but I don't know how to bind this to `basemap` property of the `map` object?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the [`setBasemap`](https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/jsapi/map-amd.html#setbasemap) function available through the Map class.

```
$("#base-map-options").on("change", function () {
    map.setBasemap(basemap[$('option:selected').val()]);
});
```